# How to import XML in protege?

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege

Is there any way to import an XML document in protege latest version 5.5.0 ?
I looked at the default plugins and tabs but it seems that none of them is suitable for this job.

Comment: Any comment on the downvote ?

Comment: Protege is an editor for OWL. XML is just a semi-structured data format with no semantics. If your file is **not** an OWL ontology in RDF/XML serialization format, that won't work. You have to go one step back and convert your XML file to OWL. There are plenty of tools available online (e.g. http://xml2owl.sourceforge.net), or you just create an XSLT script.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge we can't import XML document in protege.